# WheelView-Luke Deighton

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

This is my first time ever on stack, as most of the problem's answers are already available, but this `WheelView` by Luke Deighton, I couldn't find much about it on the web, so here it is

What I am trying to do is set a list of hours from 1 to 12 to a `WheelView`

This is one of my fragments

```
class SetTimeFragment : android.app.Fragment(), TimePresenter.TimePresenterCallback, WheelView.OnWheelItemSelectListener {

private var hours: List<String>? = null
private var days: List<String>? = null
private var minutes: List<String>? = null
private var type: List<String>? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    var view: View =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_time, container, false)
    TimePresenter(this).setDataForTimeAndDays()
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setDayslist(days)
    setHour(hours)
    setMinute(minutes)
    setTimeType(type)
}

override fun onDaysOfWeekSuccess(hours: List<String>?, minutes: List<String>?, type: List<String>?, days: List<String>?) {
    this.days =days
    this.hours =hours
    this.minutes =minutes
    this.type =type
}

fun setDayslist(days: List<String>?){
    rvDays.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    rvDays.adapter = DaysInWeekAdapter(days)
}

fun setHour(hours: List<String>?){
// the adapter which I am trying to set
    hourWheel.adapter = HoursInDayAdapter(hours)
    hourWheel.setSelectionColor(R.color.white)
}

fun setMinute(minutes: List<String>?){
    minuteWheel.adapter = MinutesInHourAdapter(minutes)
    hourWheel.setSelectionColor(R.color.white)
}

fun setTimeType(type: List<String>?){
    typeWheel.adapter = TimeTypeInDayAdapter(type)
    hourWheel.setSelectionColor(R.color.white)
}

override fun onWheelItemSelected(parent: WheelView?, itemDrawable: Drawable?, pos: Int) {
    }
}


// the adapter set above but in a different class
public class HoursInDayAdapter extends WheelArrayAdapter {
List<String> hours;

public HoursInDayAdapter(List<String> hours) {
    super(hours);
    this.hours = hours;
}

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(int position) {
    Drawable[] drawable = new Drawable[] {
            createOvalDrawable(),
            new TextDrawable(hours.get(position))
    };
    return new LayerDrawable(drawable);
}

private Drawable createOvalDrawable() {
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
    return shapeDrawable;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return hours.size();
}

}

// the list which I am passing
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The `WheelView` is not showing anything, no error nothing, the `WheelView` comes up but has nothing on its wheel, I have tried using a simple `WheelAdapter` as well, this code is mostly copy-pasted from the `MainActivity`code of `WheelView` only

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView/blob/master/WheelViewSample/src/main/java/com/lukedeighton/wheelsample/MainActivity.java

But no luck, could you guys help me with this

Comment: Show your activity code. Does this view lay out properly?

Comment: yes the layout is laid out properly, i had updated the snippet, could you check that please

Comment: @Pavlus could you help me here buddy

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the only bit of code missing was an xml attribute namely **wheelItemCount**, adding that the wheelview items got rendered.

Comment: Are you able to make its custom adapter and customize its child view ?